# How to send a dynamic template email to a mailing list on Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I have a newsletter I'd like to send every other week to the same list of users. I have a link for new users to sign up, and I'd like to let users unsubscribe at the bottom of the bi-weekly email.

Is there a way to send to a mailing list instead of just an array of users on Sendgrid?

The best I've seen is that you can make one API call to a mailing list to get the emails, but it caps you by returning a maximum of 50 users.

I've also seen that you can specify lists in marketing campaigns, but apparently you can't use dynamic templates in those campaigns? So I'd have to manually extract the HTML.

This leads me to believe I'll need to request the version of the template I want with `test_data`, grab the HTML content from that, and manually insert it into a new campaign with the mailing list ID I want?

Any ideas? Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi Sam, were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I built out a super complicated lambda-based app that does what I suggested in the last paragraph (making a series of calls and manually inserting html into a new campaign)